# Running airflow on Docker. I got this error when running airflow-init

Tags: python, docker, airflow

> File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/providers_manager.py", line 255, in _sanity_check imported_class = import_string(class_name) File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/utils/module_loading.py", line 32, in import_string module = import_module(module_path) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/importlib/**init**.py", line 127, in import_module return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level) File "", line 1006, in _gcd_import File "", line 983, in _find_and_load File "", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked File "", line 677, in _load_unlocked File "", line 728, in exec_module File "", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/providers/microsoft/azure/hooks/asb.py", line 19, in  from azure.servicebus import ServiceBusClient, ServiceBusMessage, ServiceBusSender ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'azure.servicebus'## Heading

---

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The error is "No module named 'azure.servicebus' " when I running airflow-init using docker

Answer (score 0):

You need to install `apache-airflow-providers-microsoft-azure` in the Airflow docker image.

If your are using the official image `apache/airflow`, you can create a new one, and install the libs you need:
Dockerfile

```
FROM apache/airflow:2.3.4
pip install apache-airflow-providers-microsoft-azure
```

Then build the image

```bash
docker build -t my_custom_image /path/to/Dockerfile
```

Then you can use the new image `my_custom_image` in your `docker run` command or docker compose if you are using it.

Comment: I can see that Airflow attempts to import from `azure.servicebus`, and the easiest solution is to install the provider dependency as you have explained. However, I will never use Azure; is there any way to disable this part of the startup procedure? It seems silly to install a dependency for something I'll never use.